# Is there a workaround to combine rangearea, line graph and boxplot using Apex charts? (angular)

Tags: apexcharts, ng-apexcharts

I'm working on a proof of concept which would require a line graph, rangearea graph, and box and whisker plot on the one graph.

What I have so far is the following, image,but the box and whisker part isn't rendering properly - its rendering almost like a bar graph, with no median line or tails (see image).   So either I'm doing something weird, or maybe this combination of graph types isn't supported?

[my wonky graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WxkeK.png)

I tried changing the chart types.
I can get line and boxplot working nicely, and line and rangearea working nicely, but not them all together at the same time.

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from "@angular/core";

import {
  ChartComponent,
  ApexAxisChartSeries,
  ApexChart,
  ApexTitleSubtitle,
  ApexXAxis,
  ApexDataLabels,
  ApexStroke,
  ApexYAxis,
  ApexMarkers,
  ApexFill,
  ApexForecastDataPoints,
  ApexLegend,
  ApexPlotOptions
} from "ng-apexcharts";

export type ChartOptions = {
  series: ApexAxisChartSeries;
  chart: ApexChart;
  dataLabels: ApexDataLabels;
  stroke: ApexStroke;
  xaxis: ApexXAxis;
  yaxis: ApexYAxis;
  title: ApexTitleSubtitle;
  markers: ApexMarkers;
  colors: string[];
  fill: ApexFill;
  forecastDataPoints: ApexForecastDataPoints;
  legend: ApexLegend;
  plotOptions: ApexPlotOptions;
};

@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild("chart") chart: ChartComponent;
  public chartOptions: Partial<ChartOptions>;

  constructor() {
    this.chartOptions = {
      series: [
        {
          type: "rangeArea",
          name: "range graph",

          data: [
            {
              x: "Jan",
              y: [1100, 1400]
            },
            {
              x: "Feb",
              y: [1200, 1400]
            },
            {
              x: "Mar",
              y: [1200, 1500]
            }
          ]
        },

        {
          type: "boxPlot",
          name: "norms",
          data: [
            {
              x: "Jan",
              y: [200, 800, 1000, 1400, 1600]
            },
            {
              x: "Feb",
              y: []
            },
            {
              x: "Mar",
              y: [100, 800, 1200, 1400, 1800]
            },
            {
              x: "Apr",
              y: []
            },
            {
              x: "May",
              y: [100, 800, 1200, 1400, 1800]
            },
            {
              x: "Jun",
              y: []
            },
            {
              x: "Jul",
              y: [200, 1650, 2000, 760, 2000]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          type: "line",
          name: "Paul",
          data: [
            {
              x: "Jan",
              y: 1300
            },
            {
              x: "Feb",
              y: 1400
            },
            {
              x: "Mar",
              y: 1700
            },
            {
              x: "Apr",
              y: 1700
            },
            {
              x: "May",
              y: 2500
            },
            {
              x: "Jun",
              y: 2400
            },
            {
              x: "Jul",
              y: 2600
            },
            {
              x: "Aug",
              y: 2700
            },
            {
              x: "Sep",
              y: 2800
            },
            {
              x: "Oct",
              y: 3000
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      chart: {
        height: 350,
        stacked: false,
        type: "rangeArea",
        animations: {
          speed: 500
        }
      },
      colors: ["#FFFF00", "#FFFF00", "#FF0000"],
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: false
      },

      fill: {
        opacity: [0.24, 0.5, 0.24, 0.6]
      },
      forecastDataPoints: {
        count: 2,
        dashArray: 4
      },
      stroke: {
        curve: "straight",
        width: [0, 0, 2, 2]
      },
      plotOptions: {
        boxPlot: {
          colors: {
            upper: "#FFFF00",
            lower: "#FFFF00"
          }
        }
      },

      title: {
        text: "Graph"
      },

      markers: {
        hover: {
          sizeOffset: 5
        }
      }
    };
  }
}
```